QGIS python plugin: SHA1 in code with git archive?
I inherited code from a QGIS plugin project. It was likely build upon a template created with the QGIS plugin builder. Each python code file contains a __revision__ with the following comment:
# This will get replaced with a git SHA1 when you do a git archive
__revision__ = '$Format:%H$'

I've ignored these lines for the most part. But currently I am testing and switching different versions of the plugin. For this purpose it would actually be quite handy to have the __revision__ string being replaced by the git revision, e.g. as soon as I deploy the code into the QGIS plugin directory.
The comment says I have to run git archive to trigger this replacement, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what that command does. I read the description from git-doc, it
"creates an archive ... and writes it to standard output." but it is still unclear to me how I would apply this in particular in my usecase. I don't want an archive, I just want to "crawl" through a part of the file tree and create a copy with those revision strings replaced.
Can I apply git archive in this case so that I get a copy of the file tree copied to a specific location, in which all __revision__ strings are replaced with the git revision?
Ideally I can apply this command directly when deploying the code from my dev environment to the QGIS plugin directory. That means, with my git repository / dev environment having the following file tree:
git root / dev and auxiliary_files / ...
         / qgis_plugin_directory   / python_code / ...
                                   / metadata.txt

... for deploying, basically the qgis_plugin_directory is copied to the QGIS plugin directory (e.g. C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins). I use pb_tool for that, but since no compilation is required, all it does is copying the files, i.e. if I find a equivalent command (git archive?) that does the same thing while replacing the revision strings, that would work. Anyone who has experience with this?

Maybe noteworthy: When experimenting with getting the git revision, from this question/answer I've found an useful way to get the git revision without installing additional packages/dependencies. However I can't really use this method once the plugin is installed (i.e. copied to the QGIS plugin directory), as the git root isn't part of the plugin and isn't copied as well.

# get git revision hash
def get_git_revision(base_path, short = True):
    git_dir = pathlib.Path(base_path) / '.git'
    with (git_dir / 'HEAD').open('r') as head:
        ref = head.readline().split(' ')[-1].strip()

    with (git_dir / ref).open('r') as git_hash:
        if short:
            return git_hash.readline().strip()[:8]
        else:
            return git_hash.readline().strip()


As a shell command it's git archive @ | tar Cx path/to/destination, assuming your builder sets the export-subst attribute on those files.

This is called "keywords substitution". See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+keywords+substitution , https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_ident and https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_export_subst

Thank you both for your answers. I tried to wrap my head around this with the commands and sources you provided, but I still don't get it: @phd Do I have to create a gitattributes file in which I list all the files for which I want substitutions to be done? And do I have to specify a commit when running git-archive (since in the doc it says "if git-archive[1] has been given a tree instead of a commit or a tag then no replacement will be done"). Or can you provide an example of where I would put that export-subst tag?

@jthill: Thanks for providing that command; I couldn't successfully run it. The git archive @ part runs, but the tar command complains tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '\\.\tape0'. No substituion is carried out in the resulting archive and also not if I do something like git archive --format=zip -o archives/latest.zip HEAD... what is my "builder" and how to I set it's export-subst attribute?

@Honeybear "Do I have to create a gitattributes file in which I list all the files for which I want substitutions to be done?" Yes. "And do I have to specify a commit when running git-archive…?" Yes. You can use @ which means HEAD. "…can you provide an example of where I would put that export-subst tag" echo "*.py export-subst" >> .gitattributes . Then $Format:%H$ will be expanded in all python files.

You could try tar Cxf /path/to/destination -, note the addition of f and -, or get current with your GNU tools, I don't know how long GNU's tar has understood that a redirected stdin is the default input. By "your builder" I meant whatever was used to set up your repo, It's what phd said, you need to set the attributes you want. Customizing Git has a longer discussion of export-subst.
